# Error Expected ';' when trying to #import .h file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a framework to connect this objective-c project with my swift project, but I'm getting many errors when I try to import the ViewController.h to my CompanyView.m, and there is no errors of typing or something.

I'm really stack with that, appreciate your help.

There is the code with the error(if you remove the import of ViewController.h from CompanyNow.m it build perfectly.

https://github.com/wikyburns/ProjectStructure

[image: Errors]

Comment: You have C++ in `h` files. Swift doesn't support it yet. And `.m` files doesn't support C++.  First you need to learn how to use C++ in Objective-C.

Comment: That's it, I changed the type of the .m file to Objective-C++ Source and now it's building correctly, what a stupid thing, many thanks @Cy-4AH

Comment: @Cy-4AH mind turning your comment into an answer?